# Primefaces LazyLoading Table Select First Row by Default

Tags: java, jsf, web, primefaces

Need Help on the proper way of selecting the first row of a primefaces datatable when the page is refreshed, load, sorted, paged

```
    <p:dataTable id="clientTable" widgetVar="clientTableVar"
                var="client"
                value="#{maintenanceAccountController.clientLazyDataModel}"
                paginator="true" rows="10"
                paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink}  {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {CurrentPageReport}"
                rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,20" paginatorPosition="bottom"
                pageLinks="5" lazy="true" sortBy="#{client.cclnCode}"
                sortOrder="descending"
                selection="#{maintenanceAccountController.selectedClient}"
                selectionMode="single" filterDelay="500">

                <p:column id="cclnCodeColumn" headerText="Client Code"
                    sortBy="#{client.cclnCode}" filterBy="#{client.cclnCode}"
                    filterMaxLength="10">
                    <h:outputText value="#{client.cclnCode}" />

                    <f:event listener="#{maintenanceAccountController.saveAccount}"
                        type="preRenderView"></f:event>
                </p:column>

                <p:column id="cclnNamenColumn" headerText="Client Name"
                    sortBy="#{client.cclnName}" filterBy="#{client.cclnName}"
                    filterMaxLength="50">
                    <h:outputText value="#{client.cclnName}" />
                </p:column>

            </p:dataTable>
```

I currently solve this by using this snippet in my managed bean it works that it actually selects and highlight the row.

It works because selected client is null when the page is refreshed, while paging, sorting, and filtering automatically sets the selected client to null. So when the table tries to find the selected client the if logic is executed and I can select the first row of the table.

But I just made my getter a setter and the selected row does not trigger the row selected event (Will ask that problem in a different question).

```
    public MaintenanceAccountClient getSelectedClient()
{
    if (selectedClient == null)
    {
        int count = clientLazyDataModel.getRowCount();
        int index = clientLazyDataModel.getRowIndex();

        if (index < 0 && count > 0)
        {
            clientLazyDataModel.setRowIndex(0);
            selectedClient = clientLazyDataModel.getRowData();
        }
    }

    return selectedClient;
}
```

Please note that I am using a LazyDataModel so the client list are only loaded at the RenderPhase if I am not mistaken.

I could really use some help. Sample code will really be appreciated.

---

PrimeFaces 3.5
JSF 2.1

Comment: You want to always select the first row of the table? Use the client side api of Primefaces data table. It has a javascript function called `selectRow(r, silent)`. You could attach this function to the datatable using jquery's `on()` function for the datatable events `page` `sort` and `filter`.

Comment: hH thanks for the tip but the question above is a simplification of my problem. I also want to set the selected attribute depending on a database value. So I am really looking for a problematical way of setting the value properly in a primefaces lazy datatable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i face same issue too. I have to select first row on each page select. My solution was simple

```html
 <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{protoCnt.setAdditionDetail()}" update=":rightTabForm"/>
 <p:ajax event="page" oncomplete="myTblWidget.selectRow(0);"/>
```

i have two events so on page select event="page" invokes due to  myTblWidget.selectRow(0);   rowSelect listener calls setAdditionDetail()

```
    public void setAdditionDetail() {   
    if (selected== null) {
        selected= myLazyModelList.get(0);
    } 
}
```

so it selects row on bean and client side